# How can I get multiple sub-references to appear as a range in the caption and preserving other sub-references?

Tags: cross-referencing, captions, subfloats, cleveref, subfig

I have 2 plots which in turn have 4 plots each, which I label as shown in the MWE. The code is modified ([link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/395252/how-can-i-get-multiple-sub-references-to-appear-as-a-range-in-the-caption/395270?noredirect=1#comment1033280_395270)) such that the caption of the figure reads:

> Figure 1: (a)-(d) XYZ and (e)-(h) PQR

But doing so messes the subfigure references in the main text. I only get subfigure label (i.e., a,b, ... h) without the figure number. How to get multiple sub-references without affecting other sub-references?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[subrefformat=parens,labelformat=parens]{subfig}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\makeatletter 
\renewcommand\p@subfigure{} % no figure-number prefixes in cross-refs to subfigures
\makeatother
\crefformat{subfigure}{(#2#1#3)}
\crefrangeformat{subfigure}{(#3#1#4)--(#5#2#6)}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subfloat{\label{fig_top_1}}\subfloat{\label{fig_top_2}}
    \subfloat{\label{fig_top_3}}\subfloat{\label{fig_top_4}}    
    \includegraphics[width=70mm,height=30mm]{example-image-a}

    \subfloat{\label{fig_bot_1}}\subfloat{\label{fig_bot_2}}
    \subfloat{\label{fig_bot_3}}\subfloat{\label{fig_bot_4}}    
    \includegraphics[width=70mm,height=30mm]{example-image-b}

    \caption{\cref{fig_top_1,fig_top_2,fig_top_3,fig_top_4} XYZ and 
             \crefrange{fig_bot_1}{fig_bot_4} PQR}
    \label{fig_top_bot}
\end{figure}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris \cref{fig_bot_3}. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id,
vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque Fig.~\ref{fig_bot_3}. Pellentesque
habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas
Fig.~\subref*{fig_bot_3}.
\end{document}
```

If I comment the following statements, it works fine. But I require multiple sub-references of the figure to work also.

```
\makeatletter 
\renewcommand\p@subfigure{} % no figure-number prefixes in cross-refs to subfigures
\makeatother
\crefformat{subfigure}{(#2#1#3)}
\crefrangeformat{subfigure}{(#3#1#4)--(#5#2#6)}
```

**Output**

[image]

**Output (commented statements)**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I can do it, but not using cleveref.

The AUX file shows that the alternate definitions used by  `\subref{name}` and `\subref*{name}` can also be accessed as `\ref{sub@name}` and `\pageref{sub@name}`.  Perhaps someone more fluent with cleveref can get it to work with those references.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[subrefformat=parens,labelformat=parens]{subfig}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subfloat{\label{fig_top_1}\strut}\subfloat{\label{fig_top_2}\strut}
    \subfloat{\label{fig_top_3}\strut}\subfloat{\label{fig_top_4}\strut}    
    \includegraphics[width=70mm,height=30mm]{example-image-a}

    \subfloat{\label{fig_bot_1}\strut}\subfloat{\label{fig_bot_2}\strut}
    \subfloat{\label{fig_bot_3}\strut}\subfloat{\label{fig_bot_4}\strut}    
    \includegraphics[width=70mm,height=30mm]{example-image-b}

    \caption[\ref*{sub@fig_top_1}--\ref*{sub@fig_top_4} XYZ and 
             \ref*{sub@fig_bot_1}--\ref*{sub@fig_bot_4} PQR]%
            {\subref{fig_top_1}--\subref{fig_top_4} XYZ and 
             \subref{fig_bot_1}--\subref{fig_bot_4} PQR}
    \label{fig_top_bot}
\end{figure}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris \subref{fig_bot_3}. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id,
vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque Fig.~\ref{fig_bot_3}. Pellentesque
habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas
Fig.~\subref*{fig_bot_3}.
\end{document}
```